# Removing file in Kendo Upload . Error in jquery.min,js file

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-upload

I have used the following code to remove the uploaded file on the Remove function of Kendo Upload control

```
$(".k-upload-files.k-reset").find("li").remove();
```

But I'm getting an error in jquery.min.js:

> Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Recently i had updated Kendo version to 2014.3.1411 and the error is occuring only after this update

Comment: Are you loading several versions of jQuery from the same page by any chance?

Comment: No just this one version

Answer (score 0):

Try this

$(".k-file:has([title='" + e.files[0].name + "']) .k-icon").removeClass("k-retry").addClass("k-delete").click();